# How to determine if a website is using openssl?

Tags: openssl

I have a few web application deploy on server. (no access to internet)

How can I check if they are using openSSL Library?

Is there a way to test it?

Comment: At the moment you have a good chance to test it with http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/ :>

Comment: Do you want to know if the web server supports https and uses the openssl library to do so, if the openssl command line binary is available there or if an openssl extension of eg. php is available on that server?